# Trying to declare a global variable from a function

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with trying to get the "hundredFunction()" to output as 100% inside the "gameCanvas" variable where it says "this.canvas.width = hundred;"

I need to know how to declare the output of "hundredFunction()" as a global variable so that my "gameCanvas" variable will not be declared "undefined"

I hope I explained myself correctly. Thank you in advance for any help.

(Note: I do not need to know the jQuery version of this.)

```
// this loads the function tagged on the <body>
function startGame() {
    gameCanvas.start();
}

// this will allow us to 100% width and height of canvas
function hundredFunction() {
    var n = "100";
    var p = "%";
    var wh = n.concat(p);
    var hundred = wh;
}

var test = hundredFunction();
console.log(test);

// this will declare the variables to create the canvas on the <body>
var gameCanvas = { 
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = hundred;
        this.canvas.height = hundred;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);        
    }
}
```

Comment: you could call the function, like this.`canvas.width = hundredFunction()` or use `test` variable as you already have it and of course return variable `hundred` from the function

Answer (score 2):

You should return `100%` from your`hundredFunction` and use this returned var :

```
function startGame() {
    gameCanvas.start();
}

function hundredFunction() {
    var n = "100";
    var p = "%";
    var wh = n.concat(p);
    return wh; // < Return your value
}

var hundred = hundredFunction(); // < Store it in a variable
console.log(hundred);

var gameCanvas = { 
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = hundred; // < Use it to your heart's content
        this.canvas.height = hundred;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);        
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need the `concat()` function to achieve what you're looking for :

```
function hundredFunction() {
    return '100%'; // < Return your value
}
```

Comment: Thanks :). I got it to work. Much appreciated. I will mark it as an answer when it allows me to. If you don't mind me asking, how is the format, etiquette and the overall way this short code is written in your opinion?

Comment: I don't really get why you call a function to write `100%`, you could write it down directly here : `this.canvas.height = '100%';`.

Comment: lol, you are right. I just tried this and it works. Thank you for your help. I am still learning.